# Not able to change color in Android drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have different set of colors in paint app. I am able to draw lines on canvas view with default color. But when i change the color it is changing color for all lines including old lines.

below is the code.

```
public class DrawingArea extends View {

private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private static boolean mRedoStatus = false;
private static boolean mUndoStatus = false;
private float currentBrushSize;
private float lastBrushSize;
// for Undo, Redo
private int historyPointer = 0;
private boolean erase = false;

public DrawingArea(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawingArea(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

public void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    //paths.add(drawPath);
}

public void setColor(String newColor) {
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    undonePaths.clear();
    drawPath.reset();
    drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        drawPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

public void setErase() {
    canvasBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    drawPath.reset();
    invalidate();
}

private void touch_up() {
    drawPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    paths.add(drawPath);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    drawPath = new Path();
}

public void startNew() {
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}

public void undo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {
        setEmptyStatus(false);
    }
}

public void setEmptyStatus(boolean status) {
    mRedoStatus = status;
    mUndoStatus = status;
}

public void redo() {
    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {
        setEmptyStatus(false);
    }
}

public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    currentBrushSize = pixelAmount;
    canvasPaint.setStrokeWidth(newSize);
}

public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
    lastBrushSize = lastSize;
}

public float getLastBrushSize() {
    return lastBrushSize;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the new color on your drawPaint variable. However, in your onDraw method:

```
for (Path p : paths) {
    canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);
}
```

This loop is drawing all of the previous paths using the same Paint object, drawPaint, which is why they are all drawn with the same color. A possible solution to consider is saving each Paint object along with the Path, and call drawPath for each path and its corresponding Paint.Just as you have a list of all the old paths, you can also create a list of old paints.

```
private ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
```

When you save each path to the paths list, you can add the current drawPaint to the list of paints. Then, in your onDraw method, you can change your loop to look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < paths.size() ; i++) {
    canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), paints.get(i));
}
```

This would draw each path with its corresponding paint, preserving each paths color.

Comment: Could you please show sample code. I added below code in onDraw() method but then undo is not working.           canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

Comment: Added example code. When you added the line canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint); your onDraw method is now drawing the bitmap containing all the paths to the screen, rather than drawing each path individually. Your undo removes the path from the paths list, but it can't remove the path from the canvasBitmap.

Comment: Can you please send complete code.Still i am not able to change color